# Triggering UI update by changing value in child property of ObservableProperty in .NET MAUI app

Tags: c#, maui, community-toolkit-mvvm

I'm using `CommunityToolkit.Mvvm` in my .NET MAUI app's ViewModel's. One of the `ObservableProperty`'s in my view model looks like this:

```
...
[ObservableProperty]
MyClassroomObject myClassroom;
...
```

And `MyClassroomObject` looks like this:

```
public class MyClassroomObject
{
   public Guid Id { get; set; }
   public string CourseName { get; set; }
   public List<Student> Students { get; set; } = new();
}
```

The `Student` class looks like this:

```
public class Student
{
   public Guid Id { get; set; }
   public Name { get; set; }
   public bool IsSelected { get; set; }
}
```

I bind the `Students` to a `CollectionView` and everything works fine. I then tap on a student's name to select the student and update some data which should trigger a change in the UI but it's not. Here's the method I call when I tap a student:

```
[RelayCommand]
void StudentSelected(Student selectedStudent)
{
   foreach(var item in MyClassRoom.Students)
      if(item.Id == selectedStudent.Id)
         item.IsSelected = true;
}
```

Shouldn't updating the `IsSelected` property value trigger a change in the UI? Currently, I'm not seeing any update in the UI. Any idea what maybe going on here?

Comment: Student isn’t Observable

Comment: I thought making the parent object observable made its children properties observable too. How would I make `Students` observable? Create another `[ObservableProperty]` for `Students`?

Comment: Observable isn’t inherited.  That would be very expensive.  Either make the student class inherit ObservableObject, or make the property you actually care about (IsSelected) an ObservableProperty

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Jason suggested, if you want the UI update automatically once changing the property `IsSelected` of model `Student`, you need to inherit `ObservableObject` for class `Student`.

Please refer to the sample code below:

```
public class Student : ObservableObject 
{

     private bool isSelected;

     public bool IsSelected
     {
         get => isSelected;
            
         set =>SetProperty(ref isSelected, value);
     }

}
```