# .NET MAUI Image Source Binding Update Not Updating in View

Tags: c#, .net, mvvm, maui

I am writing a C# .NET MAUI app which is utilizing MVVM and SQLite. There is an observable collection of users, which when an item is clicked on, it brings you to an edit view for that user. On this edit page, there is an `AvatarView` (via the community toolkit) which shows my default png image (svg), however, when clicked, a media picker for images displays for the user to select a new image to change the default image.

When a new image is selected, the model value is updated, but the `AvatarView` binding in the edit view is not updated with the newest value - or at least the new image is not being displayed, the original image remains in the view, so to someone using this app, it would appear that the image was not changed to their selection (even though it actually was!).

The new values are saved to my SQLite database correctly and even after I've clicked the save button on the edit view, the observable collection is updated with the newest image as expected.

I would like to use MVVM standards as best as possible, but at this point, I'm grasping at straws.

Here are the slimmed-down versions of my code:

**View**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:components="clr-namespace:TestApp.Views.Components"
             xmlns:vm="clr-namespace:TestApp.Views.ViewModels"
             x:DataType="vm:AddBowlerViewModel"
             x:Class="TestApp.Views.AddBowlerPage">
    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="70"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

        <Grid Grid.Row="0"
              RowDefinitions="Auto, *"
              ColumnDefinitions="*, Auto">
            <StackLayout Spacing="5"
                         Padding="15"
                         Margin="10">
                <components:BowlerImage ImageUrl="{Binding Bowler.ImageUrl, Mode=TwoWay}">
                    <components:BowlerImage.GestureRecognizers>
                        <TapGestureRecognizer Command="{Binding SelectBowlerImageCommand}"/>
                    </components:BowlerImage.GestureRecognizers>
                </components:BowlerImage>
                <StackLayout>
                    <Button Text="Save Changes"
                            HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"
                            Command="{Binding SaveBowlerCommand}">
                    </Button>
                </StackLayout>
            </StackLayout>
        </Grid>
    </Grid>
</ContentPage>
```

**Code Behind**

```
using TestApp.Views.ViewModels;

namespace TestApp.Views;

public partial class AddBowlerPage : ContentPage
{
    public AddBowlerPage(AddBowlerViewModel viewModel)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        BindingContext = viewModel;
    }
}
```

**Reusable Image Component (BowlerImage)**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentView xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:toolkit="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2022/maui/toolkit"
             x:Name="this"
             x:Class="TestApp.Views.Components.BowlerImage">
    <Grid BindingContext="{x:Reference this}">
        <toolkit:AvatarView ImageSource="{Binding ImageUrl}"
                            HorizontalOptions="Center"
                            VerticalOptions="Center"
                            HeightRequest="50"
                            WidthRequest="50"
                            Margin="10"
                            ZIndex="1"/>
    </Grid>
</ContentView>
```

**ViewModel**

```
using CommunityToolkit.Mvvm.ComponentModel;
using CommunityToolkit.Mvvm.Input;

using TestApp.Models;
using TestApp.Services;

namespace TestApp.Views.ViewModels;

[QueryProperty(nameof(Bowler), nameof(Bowler))]
public partial class AddBowlerViewModel(IDatabaseService data, IShellService shell) : BaseViewModel
{
    [ObservableProperty]
    private Bowler _bowler;

    [RelayCommand]
    private async Task SaveBowlerAsync()
    {
        if (Bowler is null)
        {
            return;
        }

        var (isValid, errorMessage) = Bowler.ValidateEmptyFields();
        if (!isValid)
        {
            await shell.DisplayAlert("Validation Error", errorMessage, "Ok");
            return;
        }

        var busyText = "Updating bowler...";
        if (Bowler.Id == 0)
        {
            busyText = "Creating bowler...";
            if (await data.IsBowlerExists(Bowler))
            {
                await shell.DisplayAlert("Validation Error", "This bowler already exists", "Ok");
                return;
            }
        }

        await ExecuteAsync(async () =>
        {
            if (!(Bowler.Id == 0
                ? await data.AddBowler(Bowler)
                : await data.UpdateBowler(Bowler)))
            {
                await shell.DisplayAlert("Update Error", "Unable to save bowler", "Ok");
            }
            await shell.ReturnToPage();
        }, busyText);
    }

    [RelayCommand]
    private async Task SelectBowlerImage()
    {
        var photo = await MediaPicker.Default.PickPhotoAsync();

        if (photo != null)
        {
            // save the file into local storage
            var localFilePath = Path.Combine(FileSystem.CacheDirectory, photo.FileName);
            using Stream sourceStream = await photo.OpenReadAsync();
            using FileStream localFileStream = File.OpenWrite(localFilePath);

            try
            {
                await sourceStream.CopyToAsync(localFileStream);
                Bowler.ImageUrl = localFilePath;
            }
            catch (ArgumentNullException ex)
            {
                await shell.DisplayAlert("Error", ex.Message, "Ok");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**BaseViewModel**

```
using CommunityToolkit.Mvvm.ComponentModel;

namespace TestApp.Views.ViewModels;
public partial class BaseViewModel : ObservableObject
{
    [ObservableProperty]
    private bool _isBusy;

    [ObservableProperty]
    private string _busyText;

    public async Task ExecuteAsync(Func<Task> operation, string busyText = null)
    {
        IsBusy = true;
        BusyText = busyText ?? "Processing...";
        try
        {
            await operation.Invoke();
        }
        finally
        {
            IsBusy = false;
            BusyText = "Processing...";
        }
    }
}
```

**Model**

```
using SQLite;

namespace TestApp.Models;

[Table("bowler")]
public class Bowler
{
    [PrimaryKey, AutoIncrement]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string ImageUrl { get; set; } = "account_circle.png";
    public string FirstName { get; set; } = string.Empty;
    public string LastName { get; set; } = string.Empty;

    public string FullName => $"{FirstName} {LastName}";
}
```

I have tried creating an `ObservableProperty` specifically for the image and then taking the model that is incoming from the `QueryProperty` and adding the value there, but it just feels like it's not exactly the "right way" to do it.

I've also tried using an override for `OnAppearing` in the code-behind to set it, but again, it just doesn't work as expected.

Comment: The ImageUrl property needs to be Observable

Comment: Thanks for your reply @Jason. Where do I do this? Do I just add an `ObservableProperty` attribute to the ImageUrl property within the model?

Comment: Yes.  You may need to inherit `ObservableObject` too

Comment: My issue is solved thanks to Jason pointing me in the right direction. I found a separate SO post which he also referred to a similar solution for another user. [Here is the link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75829709/6114190) I found, which solved my issue. @Jason, if you could post an answer, I would gladly mark it as the accepted answer. Thanks again!